# How to access a blockchain.info wallet's funds from another site like greenaddress.it

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I have imported a wallet to Blockchain.info but because my country now blocks the access to Blockchain.info I can't access my funds in that wallet. How can I import or somehow link my wallet to another wallet in greenaddress.it.

I have the mnemonic phrase that Blockchain.info created for me, but I don't know if it can be of any help for me to have access to my private key for that wallet without accessing Blockchain.info website. I believe if I can somehow extract the private key for that wallet I can easily import the wallet into greenaddress.it

Can anybody give me a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't move out from blockchain.info to greenaddress.it since they are using p2sh and blockchain not!

You got many solutions:

- Create new wallet on greenaddress.it and send your funds from blockchain.info to that new wallet, You can use some VPN software to access it.
- install electrum, easy, lightweight and you can import your mnemonic phrase.